# Product of $n$ terms of sequence where the $n^{th}$ term is of the form $(x^{a^n}+1)$

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus, summation, generating-functions, products

While practicing from a book I found a product in the form $$(x^{a^1}+1)\cdot(x^{a^2}+1)\cdot(x^{a^3}+1)\cdot(x^{a^4}+1)$$ and was immediately curious if I could a formula to solve the product for $n$ terms, that is, a single formula for the product $$(x^{a^1}+1)\cdot(x^{a^2}+1)\cdot(x^{a^3}+1)(x^{a^4}+1)\ldots(x^{a^n}+1)$$

After multiplying the first four terms I could see a pattern develop in the form $x^{a+a^2+a^3+a^4...a^n}+x^a+x^{a^2}+x^{a^3}+x^{a^4}...+x^{a^n}+x^{a+a^2+a^3}+x^{a+a^2+a^4}+x^{a^2+a^3+a^4}+x^{a+a^3+a^4} ...+x^{a^{n-2}+a^{n-1}+a^n} + x^{a+a^2}
+x^{a+a^3}+x^{a+a^4}+x^{a^2+a^3}+x^{a^2+a^4}+x^{a^3+a^4}...x^{a^{n-1}+n}...+x^{a+a^2+a^3+....a^{n-2}+a^{n-1}+1}$

Now I can easily find the summation of powers in the first term but cant find a formula for the summation of $x^a+x^{a^2}+x^{a^3}+x^{a^4}...+x^{a^n}$ and also can't figure out how to account for the other terms.

Comment: +1: Interesting question, which I do not know the answer to.  Nice work shown.

Comment: If its relevant in any way, the value of a I encountered in my question was 1/2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the specific value of $a=1/2$ (as mentioned in the comments), one has
$$\prod_{j=1}^n \left(x^{2^{-j}}+1\right)=\frac{x-1}{x^{2^{-n}}-1},$$
which can be easily proven by induction on $n$: if this holds for $n$, then
$$\prod_{j=1}^{n+1}\left(x^{2^{-j}}+1\right)=\frac{x-1}{x^{2^{-n}}-1}\left(x^{2^{-(n+1)}}+1\right)=\frac{x-1}{x^{2^{-(n+1)}}-1},$$
so it holds for $n+1$.

Comment: I tried the end formula in a numerical calculation  but for some reason the answers are not matching up. After taking x=5 and n=4, direct multiplication gives result 37.7989 while using the formula the answer comes out 1.8994.

Comment: Also I am very curious how did you reach this formula?

Comment: @SamarSidhu When I use the formula for that $x$ and $n$, I get $37.79896\ldots$, same as for direct multiplication. The way I came up with this formula was by noting that, when the product is all expanded, the exponents consists of $m2^{-n}$ for every integer $0\leq m<2^n$, due to the existence and uniqueness of binary representation. This means that it's a geometric series, and you can use the geometric series formula to evaluate it. (That is actually a proof, but I find the inductive proof cleaner.)

Comment: Thank you @Carl Schildkraut. As for the calculation this time I calculated the value for the denominator separately and divided by 4. I dont know what I was doing wrong last time

Answer (score 3):

Using $[n]=\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$ we can write the product as
\begin{align*}
\prod_{j=1}^n\left(x^{a^j}+1\right)=\sum_{S\subseteq [n]}x^{\sum_{j\in S}a^j}
\end{align*}
where $S$ runs over all subsets of $[n]$. A special case is $S=\emptyset$, which gives the empty sum. The empty sum is zero per definition, resulting in $x^0=1$.